# Use pattern as a Login for your application

Tags: android, authentication

Is it possible to access Android Locking Pattern Library and use it in your application as Login method?

Comment: Are you asking whether your app can ask Android to re-authenticate the user, by whatever means they have set up for their device (pattern, PIN, fingerprint, etc.)? Or are you asking whether you can have your own separate authentication mechanism for your app, that happens to use [a pattern](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/56)?

Comment: I am asking if i can have my own separate authentication mechanism for my app

Comment: Just look down @CommonWare comment below to find library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern lock is perhaps the worst available authentication option, as there are relatively few memorable patterns that users will elect to use. The only benefit is that it is somewhat difficult to automate an attack against it. In general, you would be better served using a passphrase.

That being said, there are [a few pattern lock libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/56) available for use. Android itself does not expose pattern locking in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no such thing as "Android Locking Pattern Library".**

Comment: There is [an entire category of them](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/56).

Comment: You are saying that it is impossible to use "Default Android Pattern" in your application?

Comment: I believe the question should be rephrased, because I couldn't find anything on "Android Locking Pattern Library". My suggestion is that the library name is incorrect.